# Filter object of object of array properties by key javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this objects i want to filter articles by news ,funny and sports

```
const articles = {
article_1: {
 
tags: ['news', 'funny']
},
article_2: {
tags: ['sports', 'funny']
}
}
```

i want to filter to have result

```
const articlesByTag = groupArticlesByTag(articles);

articlesByTag = {
news: ['article 1'],
funny: ['article 1', 'article 2'],
     
sports: ['article 2']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easiy achieve this result using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const articles = {
  article_1: {
    tags: ["news", "funny"],
  },
  article_2: {
    tags: ["sports", "funny"],
  },
};

function groupArticlesByTag(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {

    val.tags.forEach((tag) => {
      if (acc[tag]) {
        acc[tag].push(key);
      } else {
        acc[tag] = [key];
      }
    });

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const articlesByTag = groupArticlesByTag(articles);
console.log(articlesByTag);
```

You can even make it a bit shorter with [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const articles = {
  article_1: {
    tags: ["news", "funny"],
  },
  article_2: {
    tags: ["sports", "funny"],
  },
};

function groupArticlesByTag(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {

    val.tags.forEach((tag) => {
      (acc[tag] ??= []).push(key);
    });

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const articlesByTag = groupArticlesByTag(articles);
console.log(articlesByTag);
```

Answer (score -1):

Object.keys() -> gives an array of all the keys of an object.

.forEach() -> iterate through an array of items

If the key already exists then push to the array, otherwise create an array of length 1 with the key.

```
let groupArticlesByTag = (articles) => {
   let articlesMap = {};
  Object.keys(articles).map((x) => {
    articles[x].tags.forEach((y)=> { 
      if(articlesMap[y]==undefined){
        articlesMap[y] = [x]
      }
      else{
        articlesMap[y].push(x);
      }
    });
  });
  return articlesMap;
}
```